solution-verification | solve $ x^4+x^2+1=2^y$
the problem
Find x and y, natural numbers, knowing that $x^4+x^2+1=2^y$
my idea
I took the cases 1) if x is even then $x^4+x^2+1$ is odd

if x is odd then $x^4+x^2+1$ is again odd

so $x^4+x^2+1$ is always odd and this means that $2^y$ is also odd
But this would be true only if $y=0$
$x^4+x^2+1=1=> x^2(x^2+1)=0$ and this only happen if $x=0$
so the numbers are x=0, y=0
I put this as a solution-verification, because I'm not sure if this is the only solution and I'm not sure if this part is correct: ,, 1) if x is even then $x^4+x^2+1$ is odd 2) if x is odd then $x^4+x^2+1$ is again odd"

+1 : for elegant analysis.  Looks good.

Another way to phrase this is that $x^4+x^2=x^2(x^2+1)$. But these factors have opposite parity, so at least one is even and thus $x^4+x^2=0$ mod 2.

$n^2+n+1\equiv0\pmod2$ has no solutions

Why are you unsure of your conclusions? $x$ is even if and only if it is divisible by $2$. If $2$ divides $x$, then it also divides every power of $x$ (except $x^0$), so $x^2$ and $x^4$ are also even. Conversely, since $2$ is prime, if it divides a product, then it must divide one of the factors, so if $2$ divides $x^k, k > 1$, then it divides $x$ or divides $x^{k-1}$, but the latter means it either divides $x$ or $x^{k-2}$, etc. Eventually you are left with $2$ divides $x$ as the only possibility. Thus if a power of $x$ is even, so is $x$. Thus is $x$ is odd, so are $x^4$ and $x^2$,

The sum of two even numbers and an odd number is odd. The sum of three odd numbers is odd. Thus your two statements have to be true. And surely what I've described is pretty much what you figured out yourself. What didn't you trust about it? And you demonstrated that there cannot be another solution, since by the same argument $2^0$ is the only odd power of $2$.
